# Need help to optimise my C# code

Tags: c#, performance, datetime

I have a section of my code that seems to take a while during processing. Basically `rawArray` contains ~1.5 million rows and `tempArray` has around 1000 rows. I can see why it's slow as for each of the 1.5 million rows it has to loop through the `tempArray` and look for a match. Any hints for optimising this would be great!

```
foreach(string[] sArray in rawArray) {
    // Loop through tempArray and look for match in SRC and/or DST
    foreach (string[] sTemp in tempArray)
    {
        // SRC matches
        if (sArray[0] == sTemp[1])
        {                        
            // Set Octets value for upload
            if (sTemp[3] == "") 
            {
                sTemp[3] = "0";
            }

            // Convert to double and increment
            sTemp[3] = (System.Convert.ToDouble(sTemp[3]) + System.Convert.ToDouble(sArray[2])).ToString();
            // Date & Time
            sTemp[5] = date;
            sTemp[6] = time;
        }

        // DST matches
        if (sArray[1] == sTemp[1])
        {                        
            // Set Octets value for download
            if (sTemp[2] == "")
            {
                sTemp[2] = "0";
            }

            // Convert to double and increment
            sTemp[2] = (System.Convert.ToDouble(sTemp[2]) + System.Convert.ToDouble(sArray[2])).ToString();
            // Date & Time
            sTemp[5] = date;
            sTemp[6] = time;
        }                   
    }                
}
```

Comment: Could you please revise the title to state the purpose of this code? -1 until this is improved.

Comment: I don't have a full answer, but your comments could use some work. They tell you nothing more than the code would... assuming the variable names were the same as those in the comments, which rarely seems to be the case. Also, `sArray` and `sTemp` look like some kind of class or struct that is being treated as an array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you could build a dictionary for the temp array but it depends how often the key (index 1 of each temp row) is repeated. If you have very few repetitions then it could reduce the time because it only has to search through a subset of the 1000 temp rows.

Something along these lines:

```
Dictionary<string, List<string[]>> rowCache = new Dictionary<string, List<string[]>>();

foreach (var row in tempArray)
{
    List<string[]> keyRows;
    string key = row[1];
    if (!rowCache.TryGetValue(key, out keyRows))
    {
        keyRows = new List<string[]>();
        rowCache[key] = keyRows;
    }
    keyRows.Add(row);
}
```

Then your main loop becomes something like

```
// little helper method
public List<string[]> GetRows(string key)
{
    List<string[]> rows;
    return rowCache.TryGetValue(key, out rows) ? rows : new List<string[]>();
}
```

...

```
foreach (var row in rawArray)
{
    foreach (var srcRow in GetRows(row[0])
    {
       // perform your SRC logic here
    }

    foreach (var dstRow in GetRows(row[1])
    {
       // perform your DST logic here
    }
}
```

Another major speed improvement can probably be achieved by not using strings for entries which obviously aren't strings. You are doing a lot of double-to-string-and-back conversion which will be slow. If you can convert the input data into double when obtaining it, perform your calculations and then convert it back for output if necessary it should speed things up a lot as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice :) will post up some speed comparisons asap

Answer (score 3):

Some code issues I see:

- Code in `if (sArray[x] == sTemp[1]){}` is obviously duplicated consider extracting a function
- Conversion to ToDouble and ToString are CultureSpecific, so you code may work in USA and will be broken when invoked in Russia ( where . and , used )
- Consider possible conversion exception

It is hard to say how to speed up code your code without looking at the whole code however consider the following

- Your code invokes String->Double->String conversions 1500 million times. If possible try to switch to double types for double fields.
- Check other ways of converting to double  [Double.TryParse or Convert.ToDouble - which is faster and safer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8457934/faster-alternative-to-convert-todouble)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a fan of using empty quotes to designate an empty string.

> ```
> // Set Octets value for upload
> if (sTemp[3] == "")
> ```

Using `String.Empty` makes it clear to Mr. Maintainer that this check is *not* a typo or bug. I would much prefer this.

```
if (sTemp[3] == String.Empty
```

[Microsoft recommends against Hungarian notation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms229045(v=vs.100).aspx). It was developed for weakly and untyped languages. C# is strongly typed and modern IDEs will tell you what type a variable is. That said, removing the prefix here would be a bad idea *unless* you give your variables more meaningful names. Variable names should tell Mr. Maintainer what data they contain, not what they are. Names like `sArray` are meaningless. It tells me nothing that the IDE won't. Never forget that even if Mr. Maintainer is you, you <s>might</s> will not remember what you were thinking 6 months from now. [Write code as if the person who ends up maintaining it is a violent psychopath who knows where you live.](http://blog.codinghorror.com/coding-for-violent-psychopaths/)

Answer (score 1):

You can write common code outside of the `if` condition:

```
sTemp[5] = date;
sTemp[6] = time;
```

It will also improve your code a little bit.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! We're looking for extended answers. Can you explain why this improves the code?

Comment: In example inside both condition same code is execute. Why to wrote same code multiple times. It is better to write once.